# EOFileException suddenly

Tags: java

I get an EOF exception when line clanovi = ((HashMap) in.readObject()); from method load() executes, but not always. It occurs after 5-6, sometimes even 10 calls of load method from my servlet,totally random. Please help me, I need this solved for tomorrow morning project defense :(

Just to say ClanPostave is Serializable. I tried adding flush() to the load method but nothing helped.

```
public class Clanovi implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


HashMap<String, ClanPostave> clanovi = new HashMap<String, ClanPostave>();

public HashMap<String, ClanPostave> getClanovi() {
    return clanovi;
}

public void setClanovi(HashMap<String, ClanPostave> clanovi) {
    this.clanovi = clanovi;
}


public synchronized void save(String path){

    try {

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path + "/clanovi.dat"));
        out.writeObject(clanovi);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public synchronized void load(String path){

    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path + "/clanovi.dat"));
        clanovi = ((HashMap<String,ClanPostave>) in.readObject());
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

STACK TRACE:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Calendar.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at beans.Clanovi.load(Clanovi.java:52)
    at servlets.DodajClana.doPost(DodajClana.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EOFException is gone thanks to Joni, but now i have problem with this:

```
try {
            clanovi1.dodajClana(new ClanPostave(idclana,ime,prezime,mesto,new GregorianCalendar(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan),biografija,uloga));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clanovi1.save(path);
        clanovi1.load(path);
        HashMap<String, ClanPostave> clanovi = clanovi1.getClanovi();
```

HashMap is empty after this code. And before this change suggested by Joni it was filled with values added in that try block. What could be wrong?

Here is the whole servlet:

```
 package servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import beans.ClanPostave;
    import beans.Clanovi;
    import beans.Korisnik;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class DodajClana
     */
    public class DodajClana extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();   
            Korisnik korisnik = (Korisnik) request.getSession().getAttribute("korisnik");

            if(korisnik != null && korisnik.getAdmin()){
            String path = ctx.getRealPath("");
            String idclana = request.getParameter("idclana");
            String ime = request.getParameter("ime");
            String prezime = request.getParameter("prezime");
            String mesto = request.getParameter("mesto");
            int datumGodina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datumGodina"));
            int datumMesec = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datumMesec"))-1;
            int datumDan = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datumDan"));
            String biografija = request.getParameter("biografija");
            String uloga = request.getParameter("uloga");

            System.out.println(idclana);

            Clanovi clanovi1 = new Clanovi();
            clanovi1.load(path);

            if(!isDateValid(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan)){
                System.out.println("ne valja datum");
                request.setAttribute("greska1", "Nevalidan datum!");
            }

            if(clanovi1.getClanovi().containsKey(idclana)){
                System.out.println("ne valja id");
                request.setAttribute("greska2", "Clan sa tim ID-jem vec postoji u bazi!");
            }

            if((!isDateValid(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan))||clanovi1.getClanovi().containsKey(idclana)){

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/clanGreska.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

            boolean test = !((!isDateValid(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan))||(clanovi1.getClanovi().containsKey(idclana)) || ((!isDateValid(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan))||clanovi1.getClanovi().containsKey(idclana)));
            System.out.println(test);
            if(test){

                try {
                    clanovi1.dodajClana(new ClanPostave(idclana,ime,prezime,mesto,new GregorianCalendar(datumGodina, datumMesec, datumDan),biografija,uloga));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                clanovi1.save(path);
                try {
                    System.out.println(clanovi1.getClan(idclana));
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    System.out.println(clanovi1.getClan(idclana));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                HashMap<String, ClanPostave> clanovi = clanovi1.getClanovi();
                ctx.setAttribute("clanovi", clanovi);       
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            }

            }                   

            else request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }


        public synchronized boolean isDateValid(int year, int month, int day) {  
            boolean valid = true;  
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);  
            if (year != calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {  
                valid = false;  
            }  
            else if (month != calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {  
                valid = false;  
            }  
            else if (day != calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {  
                valid = false;  
            }  
            return valid;  
        }  



    }
```

Comment: would you please share the stack trace?

Comment: Is there any synchronization at all to stop the reader from reading an incomplete file?

Comment: Is it likely that save() and load() being sometimes called at the same time?

Comment: @JtheRocker Yes, i call first load then save.

Comment: @Joni I think not, how can i do it?

Comment: If you are always invoking load() first then save(), why not keep them inside the same function? yourNewFunction(){ load();save();}
And then call yourNewFunction() instead.

Comment: @JtheRocker
Sometimes i don't call both of them. They are used to save/load hashmap that i later use in servlet (i put it in servlet context attribute). So sometimes i just need to load it without saving

Comment: I have provided an answer, see if it helps.

Comment: @JtheRocker, yes exactly he is right, the current  approach is not thread safe, this is possible just after calling load method, another one call the load method too.

Comment: why down vote? let him learn +1

Comment: did you really save anything by calling save method? how do you use class Clanovi? would you share the Servlet class too?

Comment: @user 2511414
i added whole servlet in first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent reading an incomplete file is writing to a temporary file and then renaming it:

```
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path + "/clanovi.tmp"));
    out.writeObject(clanovi);
    out.close();
    new File(path + "/clanovi.tmp").renameTo(new File(path + "/clanovi.ovi"));
```

This means the `load` process may now not find the file on the first run, or may read old data.

Comment: thanks mate, that solved the EOFException problem,but look at my last edit in first post for new problem if you can.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use a synchronized block/function to load and save to the serialized file.

Something like -

```
 public enum Operation {
           LOAD,
           SAVE;      
 }

 synchronized void loadOrSave(String path, Operation operation) {
     if (operation == Operation.LOAD) {
         //do load here
     } else {
         //do save here
     }

 }
```

Comment: File locks only work between processes. This is all happening in the same process.

Comment: EJP - Can you explain it to me then, may be some links proving your point?

Comment: Yeah, I modified my answer. Sorry for the trouble. I got that already. Thanks a lot :)